# htaccess как сделать редирект посетителя при достижении двух условий

Tags: .htaccess

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы редирект срабатывал при достижении одновременно двух условий в файле htaccess?

1. Если HTTP_REFERER пустое значение
2. Если IP адрес REMOTE_ADDR относится к одной из подсетей
3. В случае выполнения двух условий идет редирект на https://site.com/

Пример кода:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} - [NC,OR]

RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}"    "(94\.25\.1[6-7]])|(83\.220\.23[6-9])|(31\.173\.8[0-7])|(213\.87\.16[0-3])|(178\.176\.7[2-5])"

RewriteRule .* https://site.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Будет ли такая запись корректно работать, если нет, что нужно изменить и возможно ли это в htaccess ?

Comment: работает проверил